# TypeError: mention.send is not a function - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I have been trying to code this discord bot to send a message to a certain person through DMs. The way it is supposed to work is:
`tb!send @usernamehere Hi`
Then this should send a DM message to `@usernamehere` saying, "Hi". But instead, I get an error saying `TypeError: mention.send is not a function`. Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

 if (message.author.bot) return;

 let mention = message.mentions.users.first().id;

 if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'send')) {
  console.log('ok');
  if (mention == null) return;
  message.delete();
  var mentionMessage = message.content.slice(8);
  mention.send(mentionMessage);
  message.channel.send('done!');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```js
let mention = message.mentions.users.first().id;
```

to

```js
let mention = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between using the id or mention

### ID

```js
let mention = message.mentions.users.first().id;

if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'send')) {
 console.log('ok');
 if (mention == null) {
  return;
 }
 message.delete();
 mentionMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
 client.users.cache.get(mention).send(mentionMessage);
 message.channel.send('done!');
}
```

### Or mention

```js
let mention = message.mentions.users.first();

if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'send')) {
 console.log('ok');
 if (mention == null) {
  return;
 }
 message.delete();
 mentionMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
 mention.send(mentionMessage);
 message.channel.send('done!');
}
```

Also I changed `message.content.slice(8)` to `message.content.split(' ').slice(1)` so it will work with all prefix that doesn't have a space.